# Change validation alert with request parameter

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to change a validation constraint alert by concatenating a request value but at this moment I have not found the key.

I have followed this example: http://discuss.orbeon.com/Changing-section-s-label-dynamically-td4661767.html

My control is like this:

```
<fr:c x="9" y="1" w="2" h="1">
    <xf:input id="my-field-control"
              bind="my-field-bind"
              class="my-field">
        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/my-field/label"/>
        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/my-field/hint"/>
        <xf:alert ref="$form-resources/my-field/alert[1]"
                  validation="validation-82-validation"/>
        <xf:alert ref="$form-resources/my-field/alert[2]"
                  validation="validation-61-validation"/>
        <xf:alert ref="$form-resources/my-field/alert[3]"
                  validation="validation-79-validation"/>
        <xf:alert ref="$form-resources/my-field/alert[4]"
                  validation="validation-80-validation"/>
        <xf:alert ref="$form-resources/my-field/alert[5]"
                  validation="validation-81-validation"/>
        <xf:alert ref="$form-resources/my-field/alert[6]"/>
        <xf:action ev:event="xforms-ready">
           <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-resources')/resources/resource[@xml:lang = 'es']/my-field/alert[1]" 
                        value="concat(instance('fr-form-resources')/resources/resource[@xml:lang = 'es']/my-field/alert[1],xxf:get-request-parameter('my-request-parameter'))"/>
           <xf:setvalue ref="instance('fr-form-resources')/resources/resource[@xml:lang = 'ca']/my-field/alert[1]" 
                        value="concat(instance('fr-form-resources')/resources/resource[@xml:lang = 'ca']/my-field/alert[1],xxf:get-request-parameter('my-request-parameter'))"/>
        </xf:action>
    </xf:input>
</fr:c>

<xf:instance id=""fr-form-resources"" xxf:readonly=""false"" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes=""#all"">
    <resources>
        <resource xml:lang=""es"">
            <my-field>
                <label>my field</label>
                <hint/>
                <alert>Message</alert>
                <alert>Message</alert>
                <alert>Message</alert>
                <alert>Message</alert>
                <alert>Alert to change programatically</alert>
                <alert/>  
            </my-field>
        </resource>
        <resource xml:lang=""ca"">
            <my-field>
                <label>my field</label>
                <hint/>
                <alert>Message</alert>
                <alert>Message</alert>
                <alert>Message</alert>
                <alert>Message</alert>
                <alert>Alert to change programatically</alert>
                <alert/>   
            </my-field>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</xf:instance>
```

When I change the value of the field, constraints are launched and request parameter is present because is used to check the constraint which its label I want to change but the validation message is always `'Alert to change programatically'` not `'Alert to change programatically + my-request-parameter value'`.

Comment: Hi HCP, the first step would be to move your event handler in the model, as suggested in my answer below. If that isn't enough, you might want to add some `<xf:message value="…">` statements to debug this. You'll let me know if this works for you. ‑Alex

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had two mistakes, one it was not necesary `instance('fr-form-resources')/resources...`, it was enough witth `instance('fr-form-resources')/resource[@xml:lang = 'es']/my-field/alert[1]` and also if there are several alerts related to that field taking de number in `<xf:alert` field declaration, it could not match the number shown in it with the real value needed in the code used to change dynamicly the alert as was my case.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you managed to make it work, and thank you for the update. ‑Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach of reacting to the `xforms-ready` event to update the instance with the resources makes sense. However, to run, your handler needs to be inside the `<xf:model>`, as `xforms-ready` is an event dispatched to models.

To debug this, you can also insert `<xf:message value="…">` in your action, to check that code runs, and to check that certain expressions indeed return the value you expect.